# Python xmltodict: How to preserve XML element order?

Tags: python, xml, xmltodict

I'm using *xmltodict* for XML parsing/unparsing, and I need to preserve the XML element ordering while processing one document. Toy REPL example:

```
>>> import xmltodict
>>> xml = """
... <root>
...   <a />
...   <b />
...   <a />
... </root>
... """
>>> xmltodict.parse(xml)
OrderedDict([('root', OrderedDict([('a', [None, None]), ('b', None)]))])
>>> xmltodict.unparse(_)
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<root><a></a><a></a><b></b></root>'
```

Note that the original sequence `[a, b, a]` is replaced by `[a, a, b]`. Is there any way to preserve the original order with `xmltodict`?

Comment: From [the maintainer of the project](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict/issues/111): "The guiding principle behind the design of xmltodict is to implement one simple mapping between XML and nested dict+list+string structures resembling what you would get from a JSON document, no more, no less. I have no intention of making xmltodict a full fledged XML processing framework and I think that features like the one proposed in this ticket come at the expense of the library's ease of use and code simplicity/maintainability... if you're hitting xmltodict's limitations, you should use XPath...."

Comment: So there you have it, use XPath (or lxml).

Comment: Thanks @BobDylan. I guess I'll have to throw way `xmltodict` and go straight with `lxml` :(

Comment: Maybe if you explain what you want to *do* actually, that would give people a chance to propose a solution.

Comment: @Tomalak, I'm interested on preserving the original element order. For my needs, `<root><a /><b /><a /></root>` (the original XML in my example) is not the same as `<root><a /><a /><b /></root>` (the unparsed output of xmltodict).

Comment: Yes, but what *for*? (Also, any reason why using a DOM API has not been your first choice?)

Comment: @Tomalak, the XML I provided is a simplification of one application configuration file. The elements `<a />` and `<b />` represent operations for that system, to be applied _sequentially_. The application I'm working on interacts with that system, but doesn't need to know every schema detail. I chose _xmltodict_ for convenience; for my purposes is beautifully simple, it parses directly to python dicts, which enables direct JSON serialization for other purposes.

Comment: Thank you. It's a good thing to add such a paragraph to the question to make it easier for future visitors to decide whether this is something for them or not (also to provide a little more "beef" for search engines).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not super elegant, but minidom can do the job just fine:

```
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom

xml = """
<root>
<a />
<b />
<a />
</root>
"""
doc = minidom.parseString(xml)                  # or minidom.parse(filename)
root = doc.getElementsByTagName('root')[0]      # or doc.documentElement
items = [n for n in root.childNodes if n.nodeType == doc.ELEMENT_NODE]

for item in items:
    print item.nodeName
```

You can of course use a full-blown DOM API like lxml but for the modest task of iterating some nodes in document order it's maybe not necessary.